# How can I create a PHP variable from HTML form input?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm looking to create a query to subtract a number from a MySQL field from a number entered in an HTML form.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: this is not the community for that, you should share your essay (`code`), explain more explicitly and in a clearer matter, read this : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

you can get any variable submitted from a form through the global variable $_POST, assuming that your are using the method post which is recommended when submitting form input.

example:
HTML form code

```
<form method="post" action="http://www.example.com/formPost">
...
<input type="text" name="my_number" />
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
...
</form>
```

PHP code

```
<?php
// retrieve value from input box
$my_number = $_POST['my_number'];
...
```

note, that the name for the input box is used as a key for retrieving the value someone entered in the form.

Answer (score 0):

If your HTML form is in php file then just take the value `$_POST['field_name']` and store it to a variable then write the delete query for substraction `Delete * FROM table_name WHERE id=$id` and you need to take the deletion id from that HTML form too. I just passed that id variable for an example. You should store the id variable first.

And if your page isn’t in php file then you should do this by ajax.